# What is the standard HTTP client on Android?

Tags: android, http

What is the standard (that is, built-in as part of the OS) HTTP client in Android?

Every time I search for an example of HTTP in Android, I seem to find code that uses some random third-party library that I don't have (and don't want).

Libraries are fine if they do something you need, but I would prefer to not have a dependency on something if it is available in the OS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the standard (that is, built-in as part of the OS) HTTP client in Android?

`HttpURLConnection`. It is *very* old and has an API that reflects its age, which is why most professionals do not use it.

Comment: Thanks. What kinds of problems or limitations will I run into if I try to use it? I don't need much, just the ability to send a request and receive a response asynchronously.

Comment: I'm seeing an HttpsUrlConnection, is that newer?

Comment: @user92238: `HttpURLConnection` is not asynchronous. `HttpsURLConnection` is for HTTPS (i.e., SSL, encryption, security). You'll get an instance of either of those classes depending on the scheme of the `URL` that you call `openConnection()` on. You won't run into "problems" with these classes, in that they won't break in most cases. They're just seriously clunky and have little direct support for modern security (SSL configuration, certificate pinning, etc.).

Comment: @CommonsWare :: I have been using  `HttpURLConnection` in many of my applications were I need to interact with a webservice. It does what I need, but in reference to "direct support for modern security" as you mentioned could please edit your answer to include some good alternatives to  `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: @Barns52: The leading alternative is OkHttp, whether used directly or by wrapping it in some other library that handles particular scenarios (Retrofit for REST, Glide or Picasso for images, Apollo-Android for GraphQL).

Comment: I worry about using a third-party tool. I don't know who wrote "OkHttp", or how long it will be supported. I worry that four years from now my app will no longer compile or run properly because this dependency will be long obsolete or abandoned. How do other developers manage this?

Comment: @user92238: "I don't know who wrote "OkHttp"" -- it was written by Square, as a simple Internet search will tell you. "I worry that four years from now my app will no longer compile or run properly because this dependency will be long obsolete or abandoned" -- four years from now, many things in your app may no longer compile or run properly. OkHttp is not a particular source of risk. "How do other developers manage this?" -- they keep their apps up to date.